# Create a historical of data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

Which is better way to create a historical of data in MySQL database ?

I have a table of Project, Task, Activity and Phase, and every time when update some data, need to create a historical for each change.
In fact, I was created a ProjectManager to manager the Project, Task, Activity and Phase.
Because I have these links:

*One Project is composed by many Task, Task is composed by many Activity and Activity is composed by many Phase.*

So, I don't know if create, for exemple, a Historical_Phase,a Historical_Activity, Historical_Task and Historical_Projet is the better way for my problem ?

Or a ProjetMediator_Historical is better?

I never worked with this, anyone can help me, please ?

See the ProjectMediator relashionships code in below :

```
public class ProjetMediator implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String FIND_PROJECT_BY_ID_PROJECTMEDIATOR = "ProjetMediator.findProjetMediatorByIdProjet";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_projet")
    private Projet projet;


    @ManyToMany( targetEntity=Tache.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY )
    private List<Tache> taches;

    @ManyToMany( targetEntity=Activite.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY )
    private List<Activite> activites;

    @ManyToMany( targetEntity=Phase.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY )
    private List<Phase> phases;
       //get and sets
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052488/best-practices-with-historical-data-in-mysql-databse/17053042#17053042

Comment: Duplicate of [Database design for Revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17002243/684229)

Comment: @Tomas  I update with more details, please check, the links don't have a good answer to my problem I guess. Thank you!

Comment: @NevilleK I update with more details, please check, the links don't have a good answer to my problem I guess. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a history table that's partitioned by date (week, month, quarter, year) and I'd INSERT into it with triggers.  That way you can move off old partitions as your archive and purge strategy.

All transactional tables could share that schema.  I'd prefer that to having to create dual schemas for history and transactions.  The transactional schema might not be best for analysis (e.g. star schema for the latter).

Comment: I update with more details, please check, the links don't have a good answer to my problem I guess. Thank you!