# MySQL Performance - Delete Table Rows or Just Mark a Column as Deleted

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-delete

I've read a few times that for performance reasons you best not to delete rows in a table but rather use a column to mark the rows as deleted.

e.g.: I have a table that holds members photos and when I member removes a photo I currently delete the row. I could instead just mark the photo as deleted but leave it in the table.

So rather then run a DELETE I would run a UPDATE.

Is this really a better way to use MySQL INNODB Tables or does it really not make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to preserve the data and history set a field to DELETE otherwise removed the row from your table.  No point using disk space, for data you don't need.

Comment: Can you include more information on the performance question raised, and include sources? It will make for a much better answer.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052488/best-practices-with-historical-data-in-mysql-databse